# How to add new question at the beginning of the google form with google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am writing a google app script and trying to add a new question at the beginning of the form. here is my code:
I am using google sheets to get google form url.

```
function myFunction() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetid).getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  let lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i <= lr; i++) {
    var formUrl = sheet.getRange('C' + i).getValue(); // here i get form url in which i have to add new question

    //working code
    if (formUrl != "") {
      var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
      var formitems = form.getItems();
      var item1 = form.addTextItem().setRequired(true);
      // formitems.shift(item1);
      item1.setTitle('Center Name:');
    }
  }
}
```

but i am not be able to do so, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [moveItem(item, toIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#moveitemitem,-toindex) to change the position of an Item.

**Code:**

```
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl("link here");
  var item1 = form.addTextItem().setRequired(true); //Add Item
  item1.setTitle('Center Name:'); // Set Item title
  var items = form.getItems(); // Get all Items
  form.moveItem(items[items.length - 1], 0) //Get the last Items element and move to the first index
```

**Example:**

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks the code is working fine for me, it saves my lots of time.